# Multiple transformations/actions and lazy evaluation in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working on a project on PySpark that requires processing large datasets (multiple .csv files of size around 2GB).

Let's say I have two dataframes A and B, and that **I perform some transformations on A and B separately**. Now let C be some dataframe such that:

`C = A.join(B, A.key_1 == B.key_2, "full")`

And then execute the action :

`C.count()`

Does PySpark *redo all the transformations* that I performed on A and B *plus * the full join operation of A+B each time I invoke C.count() ? Or does it memorize them somewhere to speed up the action ?

Let's say there is an additional dataframe D that is a transformation of C, **does D.count() makes PySpark redo the join between A and B ?**

I noticed that PySpark takes a lot more time on C.count() when there are transformations done on A or B than when there aren't, which makes me think that no operation is memorized before PySpark encounters the action count().

Answer (score 0):

> Does PySpark redo all the transformations that I performed on A and B *plus * the full join operation of A+B each time I invoke C.count() ? Or does it memorize them somewhere to speed up the action ?

Assuming that all your operations on all DataFrames are part of the same, single job, then Spark is able to optimize the order of operation so that no excessive calculation is required. One option that you could try is to [`cache`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence) the results of DataFrame `C` - all subsequent `count` invocations should be now much faster.

In general your machine should have enough RAM to be able to fit all *cached* data, otherwise you will have to split the persistence between the memory and disk. There are some considerations when caching though, so I am leaving a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/scala/best-practice-cache-count-take) that explains some of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll check the provided link. How do I make spark perform all the operations in one single job ? because every time I invoke an operation such as count() I see multiple stages appear in the terminal that pyspark goes through

Comment: Multiple stages is totally normal - a Stage is just a part of a Job. In general the more stages, the more data shuffling happens inside of your job, but that's a whole another topic - you can try reading this to gain some understanding (it might not be easy on the first attempt though :)) - https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark/shuffle-apache-spark-back-basics/read